# p-adic Hodge theory for singular projective varieties

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, arithmetic-geometry, hodge-theory

In p-adic Hodge theory, one has comparison theorems relating, for example, the crystalline cohomology of the special fiber of a smooth proper family with the etale cohomology of the rigid-analytic generic fiber.

The so-called rigid cohomology extends crystalline cohomology to the case of not necessarily smooth schemes. For separated schemes of finite type, rigid cohomology groups satisfy reasonable [finiteness properties](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0208027) ([in contrast with crystalline cohomology](https://arxiv.org/abs/1205.1597)). So maybe it is not entirely unreasonable to ask: if we consider rigid cohomology, does p-adic Hodge theory make sense for families of schemes with singular special fiber?